Robust way to get the current URL path
How to get current URL path with a trailing slash? Is there a robust way to have:
example.com                    => /
example.com/                   => /
example.com/index.php          => /
example.com/path/to            => /path/to/
example.com/path/to/           => /path/to/
example.com/path/to/index.php  => /path/to/

?
I thought:
$path = rtrim(dirname(parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH)), '/') . '/';

would work, but it doesn't: calling example.com/test/ which internally opens example.com/test/index.php  gives /.

As you know, URLs do not necessarily have anything to do with file system paths (or even files). If you are talking about the scenario where your server does not implement any routing or rewriting and merely loads physical files, you may want to explore $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] and $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].

/path/to and /path/to/ are fundamentally different. Why would you consider them the same?
